# blogger via idHTTP : error 400 bad request

Tags: delphi, api, delphi-7, indy, blogger

I'm trying to post to Blogger using idHTTP component, however, I'm getting "HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request" error.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var request,response,req  : TStringlist;
    auth,blogid : string;
begin
blogid    := '00000000000000000000000';
request   := TStringList.Create;
response  := TStringList.Create;
req       := TStringList.Create;

IdHTTP1.Request.Connection := 'Keep-Alive';
IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;

request.Clear();
request.Values['accountType'] := 'GOOGLE';
request.Values['Email']       := 'xxx@gmail.com';
request.Values['Passwd']      := 'yyy';
request.Values['service']     := 'blogger';

response.Text :=IdHTTP1.Post('https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin',request);
auth := response.Values['Auth'];  //working perfectly

req.Clear();
req.Text := Memo2.Lines.Text;  //put entry into request var

IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Clear();
IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('GData-Version: 2');
//IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('Authorization: GoogleLogin auth='+auth);
IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := 'GoogleLogin auth = '+auth;
IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/atom+xml';

memo1.Text := IdHTTP1.Post('https://www.blogger.com/feeds/' + blogid + '/posts/default', req); // I got "HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request" error right here.

end;
```

gor error on

```
memo1.Text := IdHTTP1.Post('https://www.blogger.com/feeds/' + blogid + '/posts/default', req);
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are posting your XML data using a `TStringList`.  Even though you are not setting the `Request.ContentType` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, posting a `TStrings` object will always encode the data as if you did.  That is likely why the server is complaining, because it will not receieve your intended XML correctly.  To post XML data, you need to use a `TStream` instead, eg:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  request, response : TStringlist;
  req : TStream;
  auth, blogid : String;
begin
  blogid := '00000000000000000000000';

  IdHTTP1.Request.Connection := 'Keep-Alive';
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;

  request := TStringList.Create;
  try
    response := TStringList.Create;
    try
      request.Values['accountType'] := 'GOOGLE';
      request.Values['Email']       := 'xxx@gmail.com';
      request.Values['Passwd']      := 'yyy';
      request.Values['service']     := 'blogger';

      IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
      response.Text := IdHTTP1.Post('https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin', request);

      auth := response.Values['Auth'];
    finally
      response.Free;
    end;
  finally
    request.Free;
  end;

  req := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    Memo2.Lines.SaveToStream(req);
    req.Position := 0;

    IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Clear;
    IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['GData-Version'] := '2';
    IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := 'GoogleLogin auth = ' + auth;
    IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/atom+xml';

    Memo1.Text := IdHTTP1.Post('https://www.blogger.com/feeds/' + blogid + '/posts/default', req);
  finally
    req.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, but after try your solution, I got "HTTP/1.0 401 UNAUTHORIZED

Comment: Sorry just need delete spaces here..

IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := 'GoogleLogin auth='+auth;